# boost smart_ptr non thread safe macro, does it really exist?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost

I have seen in some stackoverflow questions/answers people talking about a boost macro (I guess it should be set at compile time) to avoid smart_ptr thread safeness. I have been searching for it around and wasn't able to find it. Could anybody point it out?

In the other hand, using this macro will avoid the ref counting heap allocation?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety

> If your program is single-threaded and does not link to any libraries that might have used shared_ptr in its default configuration, you can #define the macro BOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS on a project-wide basis to switch to ordinary non-atomic reference count updates.

Comment: This was obviously my fault. Thanks for the link. In the other hand, does it still uses heap for the reference counting?

Comment: @Notbad: Considering that you can still pass `shared_ptr`s around, store them somewhere etc., it must be using the heap. Imagine you call a function `shared_ptr<Frob> foo()`, then how could you conserve the ref-count on the stack otherwise? The order in which references are released does not depend on the threadedness, too. Imagine `Foo` gives `Bar` a `shared_ptr`, and then `Foo` is killed.

Comment: Again, thanks for the explanation. I see now how a dumb question it was :).